# how can i detect if someone entered wrong otp

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I just trying to show error to user if he enters the wrong otp how can i achieve that because if he enters the wrong code App was crashed.

Here's my code:

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {


    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                proceedProgressDialog.dismiss();
                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                String currentUserMobile = user.getPhoneNumber();


                CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
                Query query = reference.whereEqualTo("Mobile", currentUserMobile);
                query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                String userCred = snapshot.getString("Mobile");
                                if (userCred.equals(currentUserMobile)) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE, currentUserMobile);
                                        editor.commit();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finishAffinity();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdditionalDetailsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                    }
                });

            } else {
                // Here I want to show wrong otp error
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to check if someone enters wrong otp there might be shown the error

Comment: If the app crashes it logs an exception with a message and a stack trace to the logcat output. Find those and add them to your question, so that we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: now my app was not crashing why my app crash previously but currently It was working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That will put in the else part where i write a comment to put error

```
if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    proceedProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    binding.getStartedOTP.setError("Invalid OTP");
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect OTP entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

> if (task.getException() instanceof
> FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
> Toast.makeText(Verification.this, "Incorrect OTP entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

Comment: My code working properly now but thanks for the review my question